# Python module that would create mp42 encoded ASF file

Tags: python, streaming, mpeg-4

I'm trying to capture a video using a webcam then encoding it as an mp42 asf file on a windows machine.
I managed to encode an mpeg2 file using pymedia but pymedia doesn't seem to support mp42.

I installed opencv and tried to use the python wrapper but python keeps crashing everytime I create a writer. Even with just captureing images, it seems too slow and unreliable. 
Does anyone know of a python module that allow me to create mp42 files?
Thanks,
-Ray

Answer (score 0):

According to this : http://forums.creativecow.net/readpost/291/493 mp42 is a version 2 of MP4 ISO file format. (Explained [here](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000155.shtml))

Where as according to this [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video), it is an old Microsoft's (proprietary) MPEG4 codec version 2. This was built-in under VFW (video for windows). I think FFMPEG allows encoding using -vcodec MSMPEGv2 (or something like that) as per this link: http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Video-Codecs. Though i am not sure if this is same.

If FFMPEG works, it *has* python binding **[pyffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/)** that might work for you.